# Is it okay to leave regulators heating at higher end of range of operating range?

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit, temperature, heatsink, heat-protection

IC operating range -20 to 80 degrees Celsius

Regulator IC application spec 12V in, 5V 1.5A output

Is it okay to keep IC running at 70-75 degree Celsius (with heat sink) all the time, circuit will be always running.
efficiency and out stability is fine for my application @ 70 degree.

Will this damage the IC over time or reduce the reliability of regulator IC?

or do i have cool it down to somewhere around 35 degree Celsius using more temperature spreading techniques? (fan or increasing pcb thermal conductivity )

Comment: Which IC would that be? Please link to a datasheet. It will tell you what the safe temperatures are, either at the package, or the silicon junction, or the ambient, and the parameters of the heat sink can be used to calculate what temperatures there are. However, it seems that at 1.5A your regulator would have to dissipate 10.5 Watts, and that really does not sound doable with a linear regulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to calculate the junction temperature when dissipating 10.5 watts at an ambient of 70 °C. The 10.5 watts comes from the fact that the linear regulator is dropping 7 volts to convert 12 volts to 5 volts. That volt-drop × current (1.5 amps) equals 10.5 watts.

You calculate junction temperature based on the data sheet for the regulator and your heat-sink specification whilst taking into account the minimum air-flow needed for the heat-sink to be effective. You might also need to account for local ambient warming by a few degrees.

So, get the figure for junction to case thermal resistance (\$\theta_{JC}\$) from the data sheet and multiply that by power dissipated. The result is the temperature that the junction will be at when the case is **held** at some ambient temperature. So, if the number realized is (say) 60 °C and your ambient is 70 °C then the junction will be at 130 °C.

Then you need to factor in the heat-sink. It might have a thermal-resistance to ambient of 2 °C per watt and that means that the 10.5 watts flowing through it will raise its local temperature by 21 °C.

You then add this to your local ambient temperature of 70 °C to get 91 °C and then your junction will be at 151 °C and this might be too much but, only your data sheet will tell you.

There are a few more nuances you might need to know but I'll leave that for now.

> *Will this damage the IC over time or reduce the reliability of
> regulator IC?*

If the normal expected maximum junction temperature is 150 °C and you continuously run close to or above this temperature, you will reduce the lifetime and reliability of the device.